# Почему лезет верстка на iphone?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите почему может лезть верстка на iphone 4. Сайт можно сказать не адаптивый, на телефонах отображается точно такой же как на Пк только с меньшим масштабом. Суть проблемы в том что именно на iphone сайт открывается под 320 или даже менее "пиксельное " разрешение. Как можно это обойти?? Использовал

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.85; maximum-scale=0.85; user-scalable=0;"

meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"
```

Comment: Гугл вам советует `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Visman И так пробовал

Comment: Viewport должен иметь точно такой формат как указал @Visman, а размер элементов должен настраиваться CSS-стилями

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт не адаптивный, как насчет того чтобы просто задать корректный диапазон?

```
<body>
<div style="min-width: 1000px; max-width: 100%;">
    <!-- Content here -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Такие стили и установлены.

Comment: вообще не использовать `meta viewport`

Comment: @MaximCherevatov можете скинуть пример верстки, которую вы используете?